# Método de una clase en Java no hace nada al ser llamado tras llamar otro método computacionalmente pesado o complejo

Tags: java, clase, método

Espero que la pregunta sea nueva, no se me ocurrieron muy buenas descripciones para poner en el buscador.

El código forma parte de un programa que creé para aprender a trabajar con imágenes, pero me choqué con este problema extraño que me gustaría resolver.

Creé una clase `Pares` que uso para generar una lista de pares de números positivos con cierta cota máxima.  Uno de sus métodos, `imprimirPares()`, imprime en consola la lista de pares de números positivos, de forma que en la clase principal donde se ejecuta todo creé dos listas empleando esta clase (código más abajo), y llamé al método `imprimirPares()` para cada una, pero solo funciona en el segundo caso.

Entonces, en el archivo principal tengo el código:

```
PixReader ReadIm;
ReadIm = new PixReader("data//caballitomar.jpg");

Pares list1B = new Pares(30, 70);
Pares list2B = new Pares(30, 111);

list1B.imprimirPares();  // No sale en consola
System.out.print("!!!!!");
list2B.imprimirPares(); 
System.out.print("!!");
```

Que imprime en pantalla:

```
!!!!!( 90, 23) ( 90, 84) ( 52, 109) ( 59, 5) ( 61, 3) ( 106, 63) ( 60, 46) ( 18, 101) ( 88, 79) ( 5, 38) ( 18, 77) ( 54, 86) ( 25, 73) ( 69, 53) ( 36, 29) ( 7, 76) ( 105, 14) ( 109, 20) ( 88, 92) ( 46, 99) ( 25, 98) ( 92, 74) ( 41, 62) ( 39, 96) ( 55, 53) ( 107, 50) ( 53, 70) ( 67, 0) ( 54, 16) ( 109, 93) 

!!
```

Por partes:

- `PixReader` pasa una imagen a un array bi-dimensional que guarda la información *RGB* pixel a pixel. Usaré esto más tarde en el código.
- Los pares generados dependerán de la imagen, pero el problema es independiente de esto, y usé constantes arbitrarias para crearlos. Si no llamo a `PixReader`, el método sí que funciona como es esperado. Además, si pongo la misma línea de código repetida más tarde, sí imprime en consola la lista. Haga lo que haga la primera vez que llamo `imprimirLista()` no imprime nada.

Código quizás relevante de Pares:

```
public class Pares {
    int cantidad;
    List<Integer> listaX = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> listaY = new ArrayList<>();
    int cota;
    
    public Pares(int numeropares, int cotamaxima) {
        this.cantidad=numeropares;
        Generar(cotamaxima);
    }

    public void Generar(int cotamaxima) {
        this.cota = cotamaxima;

        Random rand = new Random();
        int randomNum; 

        for (int i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {
            randomNum = rand.nextInt(cotamaxima );
            listaX.add(randomNum);
        }       

        for (int i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {
            randomNum = rand.nextInt(cotamaxima );
            listaY.add(randomNum);
        }
    }
  
    // en realidad faltan métodos, pero no los llamo en el programa .....

    public void imprimirPares() {
        if ( (this.listaX.isEmpty())||  (this.listaY.isEmpty())) {
            System.out.println("Pares no son válidos");
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < this.listaX.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print("( " + this.listaX.get(i) + ", " + this.listaY.get(i) + ") ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Pienso que el código de `PixReader` no es relevante, pero por si interesa:

```
public class PixReader {
    String path;
    RGBColor[][] pixelArr;
    int alto;
    int ancho;
    boolean proceder;

    public PixReader(String path) {
        this.path = path;
        File imagen= new File(path);
        try {
            BufferedImage bufimagen = ImageIO.read(imagen);
            proceder = true;

            this.alto = bufimagen.getHeight();
            this.ancho = bufimagen.getWidth();
            pixelArr = new RGBColor[alto][ancho];

            for (int i = 0; i < alto; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < ancho; j++) {
                    System.out.print(bufimagen.getRGB(j, i));
                    pixelArr[i][j] = new RGBColor(bufimagen.getRGB(j, i));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            proceder = false;
        }
    }

    public  RGBColor[][] getArray() {
        return pixelArr;
    }
}
```

¡Muchas gracias!

Edito: Testeé todo en un proyecto nuevo y da el mismo error. Dado que me preguntaron por la clase `RGBColor`, pongo el código "relevante" por si acaso. Ahora creo que está todo el código que ejecuto:

```
public class RGBColor {
    byte r;
    byte g;
    byte b;

    public RGBColor(byte r, byte g, byte b) {
        this.r = r;
        this.g = g;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public RGBColor(int rgb) {
        this.r = (byte) ((byte) (rgb >> 16) & 0xff);
        this.g = (byte) ((byte) (rgb >> 8) & 0xff);
        this.b = (byte) ((byte) (rgb >> 0) & 0xff);
    }

    public int getRGBint() {
        int rgb = 0;
        int unsigned;

        unsigned = r & 0xff;  // bytes to unsigned byte in an integer.
        rgb += (unsigned) << 16;

        unsigned = g & 0xff;  
        rgb += (unsigned) << 8;

        unsigned = b & 0xff;
        rgb += (unsigned);

        return rgb;
    }
}
```

Comment: Al poner el código relevante en un proyecto en blanco, se imprimen ambas listas sin problemas. Sospecho que tu problema está en otra parte de tu código. ¿Qué pasa al ejecutarlo paso a paso?

Comment: La clase Pares anda bien lo he testeado y obtengo el primero y segundo sin problemas.
( 4, 45) ( 62, 56) ( 20, 18) ( 50, 50) ( 30, 26) ( 54, 58) ( 25, 46) ( 66, 42) ( 8, 14) ( 37, 22) ( 25, 45) ( 32, 42) ( 30, 39) ( 58, 4) ( 55, 60) ( 10, 41) ( 57, 55) ( 69, 52) ( 22, 62) ( 12, 24) ( 23, 42) ( 46, 41) ( 10, 64) ( 60, 28) ( 3, 58) ( 13, 52) ( 15, 23) ( 54, 1) ( 3, 9) ( 62, 47) 
!!!!!( 30, 99) ( 46, 108) ( 28, 10) ( 54, 33) ( 34, 88) ( 29, 48) ( 24, 28) ( 20, 80) ( 7, 17) ( 44, 51) ( 69, 6) ( 98, 92) ( 27, 104) ( 21, 64) ( 16, ..............

Comment: Lobos: es personalizada, pero no hace nada especial. La tengo para manipular y cambiar entre los distintos formatos para representar RGB.

jachguate: Sí, ya digo que el código me funciona bien por partes, o si no añado lo de PixReader delante. Pero al juntar ambos no me imprime en pantalla ambas cosas

Comment: Perdón por ir cambiando información tan poco a poco, no sé cual es el protocolo aquí. El problema es independiente de Pares y RGBColor. (¿Edito la pregunta y lo quito?) Tras quitar RGBColor  sigue dando error. El problema queda localizado en PixReader, que funciona pero inutiliza de alguna forma la consola. 
 Al usarlo no se imprime nada, independientemente del tiempo que pase procesando, parece que hasta que llamo      list1B.imprimirPares();  no se "activa" la consola, y no puedo imprimir nada.  Hago este pequeño update para que nadie pierda tiempo con eso.

Answer (score 0):

Debido a un error previo en el código, para ver qué se ejecutaba en el programa incluí dentro de la clase `PixReader`, en el bucle que crea el Array de pixels, la línea de código siguiente:

`System.out.print(bufimagen.getRGB(j, i));`

Y después me olvidé de quitarla. Al no haber saltos de línea ni nada, con un tamaño mínimamente grande parece que la consola se "sobrecarga". Tanto si añado un cambio de línea como si quito el código anterior todo parece funcionar como es esperado.